# How to use a string as a part of a variable in python

Tags: string, variables

I would like to use a string as a part of the variable in a loop like this:

```
items = ['apple', 'tomato']
for item in items: 
    'eat_'+item = open("users/me/"+item+"/file.txt").read()
```

So that as an output I have 2 variables named `eat_apple` and `eat_tomato`.

Obviously, the `'eat_'+item` is wrong but to just get my idea.

P.S. I saw similar posts but neither of them helped

Comment: Assign `eat_` to a variable, and use it inside the loop.

Comment: if you mean to set `x = 'eat_'` and then say `x+item = open("users/me/"+item+"/file.txt").read()` , this doesn't help

Comment: I meant as follows: `item = pen("users/me/"+item+"/file.txt").read()`. Then, `item = 'eat_' + item`

Comment: No, this is wrong, because this `eat_` part is added to the string itself, not the variable name

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't follow your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instead of assigning the value to the variable that is a string, you can instead create a dictonary and use the variable name(which is of string type) as key and store a corresponding value to it.**
Try it:

```
items = ['apple', 'tomato']
eat_dict = dict()
for item in items: 
    eat_dict['eat_'+item] = open("users/me/"+item+"/file.txt").read()
```